# Blazor DataTable or Grid Bind Large Dataset Out of Memory Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I am using Blazor server to build an application. When I tested a 150k rows dataset to bind Blazor datatable. The Chrome page showed Out of Memory Error.  Tested with Telerik Blazor grid, it has same error. When I used Devexpress Blazor grid to test, the page show data correctly with reasonable speed. How do I fix the issue if I don't want to reduce the dataset size or change Chrome memory limit? Devexpress grid might be a choice but their current blazor UI has very limited function. My dataset is created from DbContext Factory and .net6 EF Please give me some suggestion to bind large dataset without out of memory. Thanks

Frank

```
                      <TelerikGrid Data="@cityList"
                                     Height="700px" Reorderable="true"
                                     FilterMode="@GridFilterMode.FilterMenu"
                                     FilterMenuType="@FilterMenuType.CheckBoxList"
                                     Pageable="true"  Groupable="true"
                                     Sortable="true"  Resizable="true"                                       
                                     SelectionMode="GridSelectionMode.Multiple"
                                     @bind-SelectedItems="@SelectedItems"
                                     PageSize="100" class="table table-sm table-nowrap"
                                     EditMode="@GridEditMode.Inline"  ConfirmDelete="true"
                                     OnUpdate="@UpdateItem" OnDelete="@DeleteItem"
                                    >
                                   <GridToolBar>                                     
                                    <span class="k-toolbar-spacer"></span>
                                    <GridSearchBox  Width="300px" DebounceDelay="200">
                                    </GridSearchBox>
                                    <GridCommandButton Command="ExcelExport" Icon="file-excel">Export to Excel</GridCommandButton>
                                    <GridCommandButton Command="BatchDelete" OnClick="BatchDelete" Icon="comments-remove">Batch Delete</GridCommandButton>
                                    <label>Page Size</label>
                                    <select @onchange=@ChangePageSize>
                                        <option value="100" selected>100</option>
                                        <option value="250">250</option>
                                        <option value="500">500</option>
                                        <option value="1000">1000</option>
                                        <option value="all" >all</option>
                                    </select>
                               </GridToolBar>
                                <GridSettings>
                                    <GridValidationSettings Enabled="true" />
                                </GridSettings>
                                <GridExport>
                                    <GridExcelExport FileName="CityList"  AllPages="true" />
                                </GridExport>

                                <GridColumns>
                                    <GridCheckboxColumn SelectAll="true"></GridCheckboxColumn>
                                    <GridColumn Width="8%" Field=@nameof(BasCity.CityId) Title="ID" Editable = "false"/>
                                    <GridColumn Width="10%" Field=@nameof(BasCity.Name) Title="Name" />
                                    <GridColumn Width="20%" Field=@nameof(BasCity.StateName) Title="State Name" />
                                    <GridColumn Width="20%" Field=@nameof(BasCity.CountryName) Title="Country Name" />
                                  
                                
                                    <GridCommandColumn Width="100px">
                                        <GridCommandButton Command="Edit" Icon="edit">Edit</GridCommandButton>
                                        <GridCommandButton Command="Delete" Icon="delete">Delete</GridCommandButton>
                                        <GridCommandButton Command="Save" Icon="save" ShowInEdit="true">Update</GridCommandButton>
                                        <GridCommandButton Command="Cancel" Icon="cancel" ShowInEdit="true">Cancel</GridCommandButton>
                                    </GridCommandColumn>
                                </GridColumns>
                            </TelerikGrid>
```

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
try
{

```
        await LoadListAsync(null);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        await processError?.SaveError(ex, null, "CityListOnInitializedAsync");

    }
```

}

private async Task LoadListAsync(string? searchTerm)
{

```
    try
    {
       if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
            cityList = await cityService?.ListAsync();
        else
            cityList = await cityService?.SearchListAsync(searchTerm);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        await processError?.SaveError(ex, null, "CityListLoadListAsync");

    }
```

}

Comment: Use paging or virtual scrolling and load only part of the dataset. Rendering 150k rows is unreasonable.

Comment: I did use paging for Telerik Grid 100 per page but still out of memory. But if I use Devexpress grid is fine. I don't know why for the same dataset.

Comment: That's still not good enough - pulling 150k rows to display only 20 or 30 at a time on a page? Very bad idea. You need to implement SQL server side paging. If just 10 people hit the site you will have pulled 1.5 million rows of data for no good reason. Unless the grid does SQL server side paging then using grid paging is still beyond a bad idea and design

Comment: Thanks for your information. I will try server side paging.

Comment: Telerik grid has the `OnRead` event. This event passes arguments like current page and page size to the listener. You can use those arguments to query only subset of your dataset. https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/common-features/data-binding/onread#performance

Comment: Thanks Dimitris, I just read the info about OnRead event.  Very helpful, it solved all problems.